# Using querySelector with IDs that are numbers

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors, selectors-api

From what I understand the HTML5 spec lets you use IDs that are numbers like this.

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
```

I can access these fine using `getElementById` but not with `querySelector`.  If I try do the following I get **SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12** in the console.

```
document.querySelector("#1")
```

I'm just curious why using numbers as IDs does not work `querySelector` when the HTML5 spec says these are valid.  I tried multiple browsers.

Comment: I don't think the HTML5 spec says they are valid. I'll double check...

Comment: @beautifulcoder They are valid

Comment: Nevermind, according to http://validator.w3.org/check it is valid to use numbers. Maybe modern browsers haven't quite implemented the standard?

Comment: not valid. "they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit." source: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier:~:text=they%20cannot%20start%20with%20a%20digit%2C%20two%20hyphens%2C%20or%20a%20hyphen%20followed%20by%20a%20digit.  
Perhaps you should prefix the selector with something semantic and valid related to the target.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

It is valid, but requires some special handling.  From here: http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes

> Leading digits
>
> If the first character of an identifier is numeric, you’ll need to escape it based on its Unicode code point. For example, the code point for the character 1 is U+0031, so you would escape it as \000031 or \31 .
>
> Basically, to escape any numeric character, just prefix it with \3 and append a space character ( ). Yay Unicode!

So your code would end up as (CSS first, JS second):

```
#\31  {
    background: hotpink;
}

document.getElementById('1');
document.querySelector('#\\31 ');
```

Comment: What would the syntax be for values greater than 9?  I can't get this to work with IDs like 10.

Comment: You need a space after the first character: `#\\31 0` - you can refer to http://mothereffingcssescapes.com/

Comment: Note that the space is only necessary if a character that is a hex digit immediately follows the escape sequence, in order to distinguish that character from the escape sequence. See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters for more details.

Answer (score 141):

Because while they are valid in the HTML5 spec, they are not valid in CSS, which is what "query *selector*" means.

Instead, you would have to do this: `document.querySelector("[id='1']")`, which is very long-winded considering you could give it a *meaningful* ID like `message1` or something ;)

Comment: You don't "have to" - there is a way to use an id selector with a leading digit.  I agree though that it is better to have a meaningful id.

Comment: UUIDs can start by a number.

Comment: If you have a list of ids, you can use ``document.querySelectorAll(myIds.map(id => `[id="${id}"]`).join(', '))``

Comment: Thank you very much!!! 
I spent a lot of time on "CSS Character Escape Sequence".
This is the simple and elegant way.

Comment: or `document.querySelector('[id=\'1\']')`

Answer (score 55):

I needed an approach which was automated. A recent change meant the id values used were no longer simple alphabetic characters and included numbers and special characters.

I ended up using `CSS.escape`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape

```js
console.log(CSS.escape('1'));
```

First, this is the failing case:

```js
const theId = "1";
document.querySelector(`#${theId}`);
const el = document.querySelector(`#${theId}`);
el.innerHTML = "After";
```

```html
<div id="1">Before</div>
```

And now using `CSS.escape`:

```js
const theId = "1";
const el = document.querySelector(`#${CSS.escape(theId)}`);
el.innerHTML = "After";
```

```html
<div id="1">Before</div>
```

See how it correctly changes to show `After`, demonstrating the selector worked!

Comment: As of today, when you need to deal with some strange id you don't control, this the most clean solution, also because this is supported by all modern browser.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a function I made just now for dealing with leading number ID's in CSS selectors, and it is IE safe as CSS.escape is not.

Pass the selector through this cleanSelector function before using it :

```
var cleanSelector = function(selector){
    (selector.match(/(#[0-9][^\s:,]*)/g) || []).forEach(function(n){
        selector = selector.replace(n, '[id="' + n.replace("#", "") + '"]');
    });
    return selector;
};

var myselector = ".dog #980sada_as div span#aside:hover div.apple#05crab:nth-of-type(2), .ginger #2_green_div, div.cupcake #darwin p#23434-346365-53453";

var clean_myselector = cleanSelector(myselector);

// print to show difference
console.log(myselector);
console.log(clean_myselector);

//use the new selector like normal
var elems = document.querySelectorAll( clean_myselector );
```

Answer (score 3):

From the W3C documentation [Attribute selectors syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-representation)

> Attribute values must be a valid CSS identifiers or String.

Thus, digits or alphanumeric strings with leading digit does not qualify as a valid identifier.

If you are using an ID generator utility for generating an identifier, you might end up with alpha numeric ids with leading digits.

A quick fix would be to either omit digits from the SEED of the generator( if it can be modified ) or always append a string to the id generated.

Comment: "... always append a string to the id generated" do you mean "... always **pre**pend an **alphabetic** string to the id generated"?

Comment: Yes, you need to prepend.

Answer (score 3):

Using CSS.escape(invalidID) is promising solution.

Solution Video: https://youtu.be/rH5IVJKmSOE

In Your Case:
document.querySelector("#" + CSS.escape('1'))

OR

document.querySelector("[id='1']")

Comment: Both of these methods have already been described in previous answers.

Answer (score 2):

To use dynamic Ids in the query selector have used simple code.

`this.template.querySelector("[id='"+divId+"']");`

If you are working on the iterations and want to access on id then checkout this code.
I had iteration on accounts object and using clickable event on LWC:

```
<template for:each={accounts.data} for:item="acc">
     <div key={acc.Id} id={acc.Id} class="box" onclick={handleClick}>
       {acc.Name}
     </div>
</template>
```

I wanted to access div data with using its ID when calling the `onclick` event on the div.

```
handleClick(event){
 event.dataTransfer.setData("divId", event.target.id);
 var divId = event.dataTransfer.getData("divId");

 //Using the divId in querySelector       
 var Element = this.template.querySelector("[id='"+divId+"']");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS spec says:

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
> selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
> characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
> (_); **they cannot start with a digit**, two hyphens, or a hyphen
> followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters
> and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For
> instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B&W?" or "B\26
> W\3F".

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters

Answer (score 0):

Based on the existing answers, I made this little helper function to do the job for me:

```
export function QueryID(id: string): string {
    // Declare and initialize variables
    let firstChar: string = id.charAt(0);
    let isnumber: boolean = !isNaN(parseInt(firstChar));
    let sliceId: string;
    
    // If first char is number, escape it
    if (isnumber) {
        firstChar = CSS.escape(firstChar);
        sliceId = id.slice(1);
        id = firstChar.concat(sliceId);
    }

    // Return id
    return `#${id}`.toString();
}
```