# Failed to Execute querySelectorAll on Document. How to fix?

Tags: php, zurb-foundation

**What I'm doing:**

I have links generated from a PHP array which produce it's own unique ID which should point to it's own modal (popup window) div which has a matching ID to the link ID. The modals are also auto generated using a PHP array. I am receiving this error, which I am very unfamiliar with (noob). Not sure how to fix. The modal isn't working and I am using Foundation 5's reveal plugin.

**PHP LINK ARRAY:**

```
          //more code above 

              if ($track->lyrics != null) { // If lyrics field isn't empty
                  $html .= '<a href="#" class="lyricCLicked" data-reveal-id="' . $track->id . '">Lyrics</a>';                                                                                       
                  $numTracksContainingLyrics++;  
                  foreach ($track as $value) {
                     $lyricsArray[$track->id] = $track->lyrics;
                   } 
        }
```

**MODAL DIV ARRAY**

```
foreach ($lyricsArray as $key => $value) {
$lyricModal = '<div id="' . $key .'" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>';
$lyricModal .= $value;
$lyricModal .= '<a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>';
$lyricModal .= '</div>';

echo $lyricModal;
```

}

The Results are being written to HTML source. So, the arrays are working and generating. It's just giving me this "***Failed to Execute querySelectorALl on Document : #1042 is not a valid selector***.   By the way, "1042" is one of the unique IDs being generated in case you were wondering.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` doesn't like number-only (or leading-digit) ids. There is a discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306204/using-queryselector-with-ids-that-are-numbers). If possible, I would add some letters in front of the numbers.

Comment: You're welcome. I've added it as the answer, although it seems a little unfair as the full details are in another SO topic. Ah well.

Answer (score 7):

`querySelectorAll` doesn't like number-only (or leading-digit) ids. There is a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306204/using-queryselector-with-ids-that-are-numbers). If possible, I would add some letters in front of the numbers.