# Bootstrap v4 popover not updating on state change in React

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-popover

I have a "Nightlife Coordination" app (from the Free Code Camp curriculum) that allows a user to search by city and RSVP to a bar for that night. The app keeps a list of who has RSVP'd and who is going. It is built with React and Bootstrap v4 (and Node on the back end).

I have text under each bar location that, when clicked, allows a user to RSVP or unRSVP. There is also a button that shows how many people have RSVP'd and, if clicked, will display a Bootstrap popover of the list of people who have RSVP'd.

If a user RSVPs (or unRSVPs), I want the list to update. (Currently, the *number* on the button DOES update, but not the list.)

The following two images show the problem:

Upon initial load, all is correctly functional
[image]

When the user RSVPS or unRSVPs, the number on the button correctly updates, but the list does not
[image]

Here is my code.

The list is being generated in the `data-content` attribute in the second anchor tag in the render method.

Can anyone help?

One other hint is that in my React developer tools Chrome extension, it shows the `data-content` attribute correctly updating upon RSVP and unRSVP. Is it that perhaps Bootstrap saves the contents of the `data-content` attribute in its JS file upon initial render and does not update it?

```
const React = require('react');

class Bar extends React.Component {  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      countMeIn: false, // coming from Mongo
      numberGoing: this.props.user_namesArr.length,
      user_id: this.props.twitter_id,
      user_name: this.props.user_name,
      yelp_id: this.props.yelp_id,
      user_namesArr: this.props.user_namesArr
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() { // need the same for DidMount and DidUpdate, in case user is signed in upon load (from previous session), or signs in after load
    if (this.state.user_namesArr.includes(this.props.user_name) && !this.state.countMeIn) {
      this.setState({
        countMeIn: true
      });
    }

  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) { // Need both in case user logs in after initial page load
    console.log(this.state.user_namesArr);
    if (this.state.user_namesArr.includes(this.props.user_name) && !prevState.countMeIn) {
      this.setState({
        countMeIn: true
      });
    }
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
  }


  rsvp() {
    let url = '/rsvp/?&yelp_id=' + this.props.yelp_id + '&user_id=' + this.props.twitter_id + '&user_name=' + this.props.user_name;
    fetch(url, { method: "POST" })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      let newArr = this.state.user_namesArr;
      newArr.push(this.props.user_name);
      this.setState({
        numberGoing: this.state.numberGoing + 1,
        countMeIn: true,
        user_namesArr: newArr,
      });
    })
  }

  unrsvp() {
    let url = '/unrsvp/?&yelp_id=' + this.props.yelp_id + '&user_id=' + this.props.twitter_id + '&user_name=' + this.props.user_name;
    fetch(url, { method: "POST" })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      let ind = this.state.user_namesArr.indexOf(this.props.user_name);
      let newArr = this.state.user_namesArr;
      newArr.splice(ind, 1);
      this.setState({
        numberGoing: this.state.numberGoing - 1,
        countMeIn: false,
        user_namesArr: newArr,
      });
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-lg-4 onecomponent">
        <a href={ this.props.bar_yelp_url } target="_blank">
        <div className="barname text-center">
          { this.props.name }
        </div>
        <div className="priceline">
          <img className="stars" src={ this.state.starsUrl } /> { this.props.review_count } reviews <span className="price">{ this.props.price }</span>
        </div>
        <div className="image">
          <img class="mainimg" src={ this.props.image_url } />
        </div>
        <div className="address text-center">
          { this.props.loc[0] }., { this.props.loc[1] }
        </div>
        </a>
        <hr/>
        <div className="text-center">
          <a tabindex="0" role="button" className="btn btn-success" data-toggle={ this.state.user_namesArr.length > 0 ? "popover" : "" } data-trigger="focus" title="Who's In?" data-content={ this.state.user_namesArr }>
            { this.state.numberGoing } going
          </a>
          {
            this.props.loggedIn ?
            this.state.countMeIn ?
            <span className="going" onClick={ () => this.unrsvp() }>You're going!</span> : // if logged in and already RSVP'd
            <span className="rsvpdetails" onClick={ () => this.rsvp() }>Count me in!</span> : // if logged in but not yet RSVP'd
            <span> Please log in </span> // if not logged in
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

module.exports = Bar;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with Reactstrap. I simply added `reactstrap` to my package.json file, and used the Reactstrap code.

```
const React = require('react');
import { Button, Popover, PopoverHeader, PopoverBody } from 'reactstrap';

class Bar extends React.Component {  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      countMeIn: false, // coming from Mongo
      numberGoing: this.props.user_namesArr.length,
      user_id: this.props.twitter_id,
      user_name: this.props.user_name,
      yelp_id: this.props.yelp_id,
      user_namesArr: this.props.user_namesArr,
      popover: false
    };
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() { // need the same for DidMount and DidUpdate, in case user is signed in upon load (from previous session), or signs in after load
    if (this.state.user_namesArr.includes(this.props.user_name) && !this.state.countMeIn) {
      this.setState({
        countMeIn: true
      });
    }        
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.user_namesArr.includes(this.props.user_name) && !prevState.countMeIn) {
      this.setState({
        countMeIn: true
      });
    }
  }


  rsvp() {
    let url = '/rsvp/?&yelp_id=' + this.props.yelp_id + '&user_id=' + this.props.twitter_id + '&user_name=' + this.props.user_name;
    fetch(url, { method: "POST" })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      let newArr = this.state.user_namesArr;
      newArr.push(this.props.user_name);
      this.setState({
        user_namesArr: newArr,
        numberGoing: this.state.numberGoing + 1,
        countMeIn: true
      });
    })
  }

  unrsvp() {
    let url = '/unrsvp/?&yelp_id=' + this.props.yelp_id + '&user_id=' + this.props.twitter_id + '&user_name=' + this.props.user_name;
    fetch(url, { method: "POST" })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      let ind = this.state.user_namesArr.indexOf(this.props.user_name);
      let newArr = this.state.user_namesArr;
      newArr.splice(ind, 1);
      this.setState({
        user_namesArr: newArr,
        numberGoing: this.state.numberGoing - 1,
        countMeIn: false
      });
    })
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      popover: !this.state.popover
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-lg-4 onecomponent">
        <a href={ this.props.bar_yelp_url } target="_blank">
        <div className="barname text-center">
          { this.props.name }
        </div>
        <div className="priceline">
          <img className="stars" src={ this.state.starsUrl } /> { this.props.review_count } reviews <span className="price">{ this.props.price }</span>
        </div>
        <div className="image">
          <img class="mainimg" src={ this.props.image_url } />
        </div>
        <div className="address text-center">
          { this.props.loc[0] }., { this.props.loc[1] }
        </div>
        </a>
        <hr/>
        <div className="text-center">
          { /* For this to work, id must have leading letters, otherwise throws massive errors. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898873/failed-to-execute-queryselectorall-on-document-how-to-fix */ }
          <Button id={ "abc" + this.props.yelp_id } className="btn btn-success" onClick={ this.toggle }>{ this.state.numberGoing } going</Button>
          <Popover placement="right" isOpen={ this.state.popover } target={ "abc" + this.props.yelp_id } toggle={ this.toggle }>
            <PopoverHeader>Who's In?</PopoverHeader>
            <PopoverBody>{ this.state.user_namesArr }</PopoverBody>
          </Popover>
          {
            this.props.loggedIn ?
            this.state.countMeIn ?
            <span className="going" onClick={ () => this.unrsvp() }>You're going!</span> : // if logged in and already RSVP'd
            <span className="rsvpdetails" onClick={ () => this.rsvp() }>Count me in!</span> : // if logged in but not yet RSVP'd
            <span> Please log in </span> // if not logged in
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

module.exports = Bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `ref` could help ... but why not use `reactstrap` and more important why not `react-popper` ...? It's well known (https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/#react-vuejs-angular-angularjs-emberjs-etc-integration) that many libraries doesn't work well with react or any other (virtual) DOM managers.

Do you really need jQuery?

Using react portals you can remove all theese dependencies.

Comment: I'm gonna go back and try it with Reactstrap

Comment: It works with Reactstrap. I just added an answer with code. Thanks for your help : )