# Tried to use querySelectorAll but failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

I want to select the first `id` that has class `a`.

```
<li class="a" id="1">1</li>
<li class="a" id="2">2</li>
<li class="a" id="3">3</li>
```

```js
var c = document.querySelectorAll(".a#1");
c.remove();
```

I use querySelectorAll but it got an error of

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.a #1' is not a valid selector.
```

I know in jquery it is done like `$('.a#1').remove()` and it will work *but I'm using zepto*, so I have to figure out in pure js.

Comment: Remove space between class and id`document.querySelectorAll("#1.a");`

Comment: Out of pure interest, why `querySelectorAll(".a#3");`? You have the `id`, which *should* be unique, so couldn't you just use the (much more direct) `getElementById("3");`?

Comment: @AdamKewley i have other id in one page for other elements.

Comment: You can't reuse IDs in a single document. They're called IDs for a reason.

Comment: Hey, I'm unsure what you mean. Do you mean that you're using the same `id` elsewhere within the same page? If so, you might want to rethink your design. If the `id` is somehow relevant to your backend, rather than a unique identifier of a `html` element, then you should hold it as metadata; for example, `<li data-id="3">3</li>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id name with the number is not valid but you can query like below

```
document.querySelector('.a#\\31');
```

> If the first character of an identifier is numeric, you’ll need to
>   escape it based on its Unicode code point. For example, the code point
>   for the character 1 is U+0031, so you would escape it as \000031 or
>   \31 .

For more information refer this [Using querySelector with IDs that are numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306204/using-queryselector-with-ids-that-are-numbers)