# Replace leading numbers with Javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

As a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306204/using-queryselector-with-ids-that-are-numbers) (not by me), I need to replace leading numbers of an id with `\\3n` (where n is the number we're replacing).

Some examples:

```
"1foo"    -> "\\31foo"
"1foo1"   -> "\\31foo1"
"12foo"   -> "\\31\\32foo"
"12fo3o4" -> "\\31\\32fo3o4"
"foo123"  -> "foo123"
```

Below is a solution that replaces every instance of the number, but I don't know enough regex to make it stop once it hits a non-number.

```
function magic (str) {
    return str.replace(/([0-9])/g, "\\3$1");
}
```

... Or is regex a bad way to go? I guess it would be easy enough to do it, just looping over each character of the string manually.

Comment: can you post your expected out

Comment: @Raghavendra I think I did. After the arrow in the examples is the expected output.

Comment: I think you need to use a reverse string approach here and use a look-ahead.

Comment: you can do like this '123fo3o4'.split(/(\d+)/) in my opinion

Comment: @Raghavendra and then run through the first one with numbers, replace each with the backslash string and put it all together? It could work, yes. But then I think I'd rather just use a regular `for ... of` loop to traverse the string and break out once we hit a non-digit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve what you need using a reverse string + look-ahead approach:

```js
function revStr(str) {
    return str.split('').reverse().join('');
}

var s = "12fo3o4";
document.write(revStr(revStr(s).replace(/\d(?=\d*$)/g, function (m) {
    return m + "3\\\\";
 }))
);
```

The regex is matching a number that can be followed by 0 or more numbers only until the end (which is actually start) of a reversed string (with `\d(?=\d*$)`). The callback allows to manipulate the match (we just add reversed `\\` and `3`. Then, we just reverse the result.

Answer (score 4):

Just use two steps: first find the prefix, then operate on its characters:

```
s.replace(/^\d+/, function (m) {
    return [].map.call(m, function (c) {
        return '\\3' + c;
    }).join('');
});
```

No need to emulate any features.

Comment: yes nice one. got new one today, missed to see the replace api

Comment: This won't work in old browsers (like IE8), otherwise, a nice one. Still, it also performs split and join. I also think you need to use `\\\\3` to get actually `\\3` in the replacement string.

Comment: The \\ vs \\\\ part is moot for me personally, but actually the browser support isn't. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would have done it:

```js
function replace(str) {
    var re = /^([\d]*)/;
    var match = str.match(re)[0];        
    var replaced = match.replace(/([\d])/g, "\\3$1");        
    str = str.replace(match, replaced);
    return str;
}

document.write(replace("12fo3o4"));
```

Don't get me wrong: the other answers are fine! My focus was more on readability.

Comment: Good solution, and you don't even need the `if` test.