# Error while query selector on numeric value

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to set checkbox value for a filter component using query selector (without jquery). If the value for the element is string then query selection is success however if it is a numeric it fails.

```
<div>
  <span>Manufacturer</span>
   <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="manufacturer" value="apple">Apple</label>
</div>

<div>
  <span>Screen Size</span>
   <label>
   <input type="checkbox" value="16" name="storage">16 GB</label>
</div>
<button>Select</button>


 document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
   document.querySelector('input[name=manufacturer][value=apple]').checked = true;
   document.querySelector('input[name=storage][value=16]').checked = true;
 })
```

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'input[name=storage][value=16]' is not a valid selector.

https://jsfiddle.net/byqwsdog/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306204/using-queryselector-with-ids-that-are-numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use `"` for the value of your selector : `[key="value"]`

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',function(){
  document.querySelector('input[name="manufacturer"][value="apple"]').checked = true;
  document.querySelector('input[name="storage"][value="16"]').checked = true;
})
```

Comment: Thanks @stephanen & Quentin

Answer (score 1):

See [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation):

> Attribute values must be CSS identifiers or strings.

---

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); **they cannot start with a digit**, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
>   by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any
>   ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance,
>   the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

`16` starts with a digit, so it (unlike `manufacturer`, `apple` and `storage`) cannot be an identifier.

---

> Strings can either be written with double quotes or with single quotes.

`16` is not written with either of those, so it isn't a string.

---

You need to quote the number.

```
document.querySelector('input[name=storage][value="16"]')
```