# Bootstrap Modal does not work with Version 4.4.1

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a normal modal dialog. It was working with Bootstrap Version 4.1.0. 
Now I upgraded to Version 4.4.1 and it does not work any more. Why is that? 
I think there are no differences between both versions regarding modal dialogs.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel_1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="update" method="POST">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel_1">Edit</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Test

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Schließen</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Speichern</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#1">
    Open Modal
</button>
```

Find the Bootstrap versions here:

- [Bootstrap 4.1.0](https://codepen.io/ktatsache/pen/povQozW)
- [Bootstrap 4.4.1](https://codepen.io/ktatsache/pen/yLyQBdz)

**Update 1:**

The following workaround works:

```
    $('button[data-toggle=modal]').click(function(){      
      $(".modal").modal();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with your modal `id` being numeric. If you change the modal's `id` to `_1` and the button's `data-target` to `#_1` it [starts working](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/rNaQama).

---

<strike>Looking further into this issue, it turns out in your example,</strike>

```
document.getElementById('1')
```

... does return the modal, but

```
document.querySelector('#1')
```

... returns an error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#1' is not a valid selector.
```

My wild guess is that, internally, Bootstrap uses `querySelector` passing it the `data-target` attribute of your button. However, since no error is being shown, I'm guessing this all happens in a `try`/`catch` block. I might be wrong, though, I'm simply speculating.

---

***...and,*** looking [even further](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306204/using-queryselector-with-ids-that-are-numbers) into the issue it turns out selectors starting with digits ***are, technically, valid*** but they require some further handling. Namely, your `<button>`s `data-target` attribute must be `data-target="#\31"` or `data-target="#\000031"`, if you really want to use numeric ids.

See it [working](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/zYxMxjB).

And it's not even Bootstrap specific, it's how DOM selectors work:

```css
#\31 { color: red; }
.\32 { color: blue; }
```

```html
<span id="1">red</span>
<span class="2">blue</span>
```

---

One more thing (not directly related): you are missing the required `popper.js` import (see [Quickstart](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start)). It's required for popups, tooltips and the like, which places them directly on `<body>` but positions them correctly as if they were children of the element beeing hovered, so that the popup can overflow parents with `overflow: hidden`. As a general rule, you want to include it.