# Product filter - Show results based on multiple checkboxes selected/deselected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox, filter

I'm building a product filter to narrow down monitor choices based on specs such as resolution, response time, brand etc.

I have created divs for each result, the specs are classes.

Each checkbox has a value attribute. When checked this attribute is stored in the map object. This is so that when I deselect a checkbox, it is removed from the map object and visa versa.

The results of the map object are joined together with "." between and then
stored in variable **assignedTo**, this is being logged so you can see which have been selected.

My problem now is how do I show all the divs that contain the classes stored in **assignedTo**?

I've tried using **document.querySelectorAll** and then looping through that by displaying block but there are two issues:

1. I get an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '...' is not a valid selector"
2. If I am successful in looping through and displaying each result, if I uncheck a box, how do I get that result to disappear?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':checkbox[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    var assignedTo = $(':checkbox[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
        return $(this).attr('value');
      })
      .get().join(".");
    console.log(assignedTo);
    document.querySelectorAll("div.result." + assignedTo).forEach(div => div.style.display = "block")
  });
});
```

```css
.result {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: none;
}

div.results {
  width: 70%;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 10%;
}

div#filters {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #0077ce;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Find your monitor</h1>
  <div id="filters">
    <h3>Recommended For</h3>
    <ul class="recommended">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="home" id="filter-home" />
        <label for="filter-home">Home</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="office" id="filter-office" />
        <label for="filter-office">Office</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="gaming" id="filter-gaming" />
        <label for="filter-gaming">Gaming</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Size</h3>
    <ul class="-monitor-size">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="24inch" id="filter-24inch" />
        <label for="filter-24inch">24inch</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="32inch" id="filter-32inch" />
        <label for="filter-32inch">32inch</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="40inch" id="filter-40inch" />
        <label for="filter-40inch">40inch</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Resolution</h3>
    <ul class="monitor-resolution">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1080p" id="filter-1080p" />
        <label for="filter-1080p">1080p</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="4K" id="filter-4K" />
        <label for="filter-4K">4K</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="5K" id="filter-5K" />
        <label for="filter-5K">5K</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Response Time</h3>
    <ul class="monitor-responsetime">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1ms" id="filter-1ms" />
        <label for="filter-1ms">1ms</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="5ms" id="filter-5ms" />
        <label for="filter-5ms">5ms</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="10ms" id="filter-10ms" />
        <label for="filter-10ms">10ms</label>
      </li>

    </ul>
    <h3>Brand</h3>
    <ul class="monitor-brand">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="branda" id="filter-branda" />
        <label for="filter-branda">Brand A</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="brandb" id="filter-brandb" />
        <label for="filter-brandb">Brand B</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="brandc" id="filter-brandc" />
        <label for="filter-brandc">Brand C</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="brandd" id="filter-brandd" />
        <label for="filter-brandd">Brand D</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="brande" id="filter-brande" />
        <label for="filter-brande">Brand E</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="brandf" id="filter-brandf" />
        <label for="filter-brandf">Brand F</label>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="results">
    <div class="result gaming monitor 32inch 4K 5ms branda">32inch 4K Monitor - Brand A <span class="btn">Order</span></div>
    <div class="result gaming monitor 32inch 4K 5ms branda">32inch 4K Monitor - Brand A <span class="btn">Order</span></div>
    <div class="result gaming monitor 32inch 5K 1ms brandb">32inch 5K Monitor - Brand B<span class="btn">Order</span></div>
    <div class="result gaming monitor 40inch 5K 1ms brandc">40inch 5K Monitor - Brand C<span class="btn">Order</span></div>
    <div class="result office monitor 24inch 1080p 10ms brandd">24inch 1080p Monitor - Brand D<span class="btn">Order</span></div>
    <div class="result home monitor 24inch 4K 5ms brandd">24inch 4K Monitor - Brand D <span class="btn">Order</span></div>


    <div class="result gaming monitor 32inch 5K 1ms brande">32inch 5K Monitor - Brand E<span class="btn">Order</span></div>
    <div class="result gaming monitor 40inch 5K 1ms brande">40inch 5K Monitor - Brand E<span class="btn">Order</span></div>
    <div class="result office monitor 24inch 1080p 10ms brande">24inch 1080p Monitor - Brand E<span class="btn">Order</span></div>
    <div class="result home monitor 24inch 4K 5ms brandf">24inch 4K Monitor - Brand F <span class="btn">Order</span></div>
    <div class="result home monitor 24inch 4K 5ms brandf">24inch 4K Monitor - Brand F <span class="btn">Order</span></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `querySelector` has problems with [selectors that start with a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306204/using-queryselector-with-ids-that-are-numbers). You can use the selectors if you escape the first number, in the code below `r.replace(/^(\d)/, '\\3' + '$1 ')`.
2. Since you are cycling through the selectors, you can just hide all the elements before showing the results. In the code below, `document.querySelectorAll('div.result').forEach(div => div.style.display = "none");` just before the cycle.

I have also added a condition in case nothing is selected. In your code, it led to an error.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':checkbox[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    var assignedTo = $(':checkbox[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
    let r = $(this).attr('value');
    r = r.replace(/^(\d)/, '\\3' + '$1 ');
        return r;
      })
      .get().join(".");
    console.log(assignedTo);
    document.querySelectorAll('div.result').forEach(div => div.style.display = "none");
    if (assignedTo !== ""){
    document.querySelectorAll("div.result." + assignedTo).forEach(div => div.style.display = "block");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.result {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: none;
}

div.results {
  width: 70%;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 10%;
}

div#filters {
  width: 20%;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #0077ce;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Find your monitor</h1>
  <div id="filters">
    <h3>Recommended For</h3>
    <ul class="recommended">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="home" id="filter-home" />
        <label for="filter-home">Home</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="office" id="filter-office" />
        <label for="filter-office">Office</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="gaming" id="filter-gaming" />
        <label for="filter-gaming">Gaming</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Size</h3>
    <ul class="-monitor-size">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="24inch" id="filter-24inch" />
        <label for="filter-24inch">24inch</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="32inch" id="filter-32inch" />
        <label for="filter-32inch">32inch</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="40inch" id="filter-40inch" />
        <label for="filter-40inch">40inch</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Resolution</h3>
    <ul class="monitor-resolution">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1080p" id="filter-1080p" />
        <label for="filter-1080p">1080p</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="4K" id="filter-4K" />
        <label for="filter-4K">4K</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="5K" id="filter-5K" />
        <label for="filter-5K">5K</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Response Time</h3>
    <ul class="monitor-responsetime">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="1ms" id="filter-1ms" />
        <label for="filter-1ms">1ms</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="5ms" id="filter-5ms" />
        <label for="filter-5ms">5ms</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="10ms" id="filter-10ms" />
        <label for="filter-10ms">10ms</label>
      </li>

    </ul>
    <h3>Brand</h3>
    <ul class="monitor-brand">
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="branda" id="filter-branda" />
        <label for="filter-branda">Brand A</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="brandb" id="filter-brandb" />
        <label for="filter-brandb">Brand B</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="brandc" id="filter-brandc" />
        <label for="filter-brandc">Brand C</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="brandd" id="filter-brandd" />
        <label for="filter-brandd">Brand D</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="brande" id="filter-brande" />
        <label for="filter-brande">Brand E</label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" value="brandf" id="filter-brandf" />
        <label for="filter-brandf">Brand F</label>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="results">
    <div class="result gaming monitor 32inch 4K 5ms branda">32inch 4K Monitor - Brand A <span class="btn">Order</span></div>
    <div class="result gaming monitor 32inch 4K 5ms branda">32inch 4K Monitor - Brand A <span class="btn">Order</span></div>
    <div class="result gaming monitor 32inch 5K 1ms brandb">32inch 5K Monitor - Brand B<span class="btn">Order</span></div>
    <div class="result gaming monitor 40inch 5K 1ms brandc">40inch 5K Monitor - Brand C<span class="btn">Order</span></div>
    <div class="result office monitor 24inch 1080p 10ms brandd">24inch 1080p Monitor - Brand D<span class="btn">Order</span></div>
    <div class="result home monitor 24inch 4K 5ms brandd">24inch 4K Monitor - Brand D <span class="btn">Order</span></div>


    <div class="result gaming monitor 32inch 5K 1ms brande">32inch 5K Monitor - Brand E<span class="btn">Order</span></div>
    <div class="result gaming monitor 40inch 5K 1ms brande">40inch 5K Monitor - Brand E<span class="btn">Order</span></div>
    <div class="result office monitor 24inch 1080p 10ms brande">24inch 1080p Monitor - Brand E<span class="btn">Order</span></div>
    <div class="result home monitor 24inch 4K 5ms brandf">24inch 4K Monitor - Brand F <span class="btn">Order</span></div>
    <div class="result home monitor 24inch 4K 5ms brandf">24inch 4K Monitor - Brand F <span class="btn">Order</span></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I would have never thought of that. After implementing I also realised selecting multiple checkboxes per category doesn't quite work. So I added this code to stop the user from selecting multiple boxes (radio buttons weren't an option as the user needs to also deselect). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709209/html-select-only-one-checkbox-in-a-group