# "document.querySelector(...) is null" even tho it exist

Tags: javascript, class, queryselector

I created 64 class in numbers (1,2,3,4...) and it seems that there are a lot of case specific things to do so I can use them normally like this

```
document.querySelector(".\\" + number)
```

For some reason when I try to create an img inside the div it says that it dosen't exist.

Here's the code related to the error:

HTML:

```
<div id="board">
<div style="width: 61.2219px; height: 61.2219px;" class="1"></div>
<div style="width: 61.2219px; height: 61.2219px; background-color: white;" class="2"></div>
<div style="width: 61.2219px; height: 61.2219px;" class="3"></div>
<div style="width: 61.2219px; height: 61.2219px; background-color: white;" class="4"></div>
<div style="width: 61.2219px; height: 61.2219px;" class="5"></div>
<div style="width: 61.2219px; height: 61.2219px; background-color: white;" class="6"></div>
...
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
while (x != 8)
{ **// Generates DIV**
  if (last == 0)
  {
    last = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    last = 0;
  }

  while (y != 8)
  {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.width = width;
      div.style.height = width;
    if (last == 0)
    {
      div.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      last = 1;
    } else 
    {
      last = 0;
    }
    div.classList.add(((x*8)+y)+1)
    board.appendChild(div);
    y++;
  }
  y=0
  x++;
}
...
while(x != startpos_len)
{
  console.log(x);
  let name = ".\\" + (x+1)
  var imgPiece = document.createElement("img");
  switch(startpos[x])
  {
    case "BR":
      img.src = "."
    default:
      // alert("Startpos contain errors")
  }
  **document.querySelector("div" + name).appendChild(imgPiece);**
  x++;
}
```

PS: This is a chess game

I tried reading documentation on Mozilla, w3school and similar error on stack overflow, but nothing was working.

Also defer in  didn't change anything

Changing to ID's or adding letters in the class didn't work

Comment: Use `id` instead of `class`.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_class.asp) class names must begin with a letter.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306204/using-queryselector-with-ids-that-are-numbers?

Comment: Why do you have `\\` in your selector when its not in class? Should it not be `"." + x+1`?

Comment: This isnt the problem. You can use class with numbers like this querySelector(".\\" + 1). Also using ID didn't work and adding letters in the class didn't work

Comment: RaJesh, class with numbers are case specific and requires .\\1 to work else it will fail

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
    <anonymous> http://localhost:5500/main.js:133

Comment: Your selector syntax is simply incorrect. If you use `\`div[class='${x+1}']\`` it does work though why not simply use better `id` attributes, eg `id="piece-1"`

Comment: Yes, already tried that, it's in the question details

Comment: Do you want the full code to try it yourself

Comment: I cannot see it. What **exactly** did you try?

Comment: I did not update the code but it was pos1, pos2...

Comment: it's highly unusual to give a classname just a number. if you really want a number in there, try adding a letter first. 'x1' and 'x2' etc

Answer (score 1):

Your selector syntax is incorrect.

Your options are...

Preferably use `id` attributes that are actually selectable. This makes sense given you seem to want unique elements (chessboard positions)

```html
<div style="width: 61.2219px; height: 61.2219px;" id="pos-1"></div>
```

```js
document.getElementById(`pos-${x+1}`)?.appendChild(imgPiece);
```

*OR*

Not recommended... keep the (bad) numeric classes and use an attribute selector. Note the quotes around the value are required

```js
document.querySelector(`div[class='${x+1}']`)?.appendChild(imgPiece);
```

Note that this only works with class attributes that are single-token. If there are other classes involved, eg `class="foo bar baz 1"`, it gets more complex

```js
document.querySelector(
  `div[class='1'], div[class^='1 '], div[class$=' 1'], div[class*=' 1 ']`
);
```

Comment: This isn't... what?

Comment: [class="x"] is wrong. The selector for a class begins with a '.'

Comment: '.pos-1' is a class selector

Comment: @Ringo I specifically said _"use an attribute selector"_. That is the only way to select the elements in OP's question

Comment: Was "?" a typo right before appendChild

Comment: i see what you're doing, but it's not a good solution at all. Why would you even recommend that

Comment: @4C3B13D4RT No, it's just type safety. Both methods may return `null`

Comment: ? is not a typo, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: @Ringo sometimes the HTML cannot be changed

Comment: you didn't read the post then

Comment: @Ringo cover-to-cover. In the spirit of providing canonical answers to questions, I will leave the 2nd option as the only way I could see to select elements by numeric classname

Comment: I tried using class before using class and it didn't work, but using id with text in front worked. I don't know why I complicated my life.

Comment: Your adding the comment recommending not to do it that way is good, thanks.