# Set hidden pardot field using javascript

Tags: javascript, sfdc, pardot

I'm trying to set a hidden Pardot field (inside an iframe).

When I manually enter the query selector in my chrome console I'm able to get the element, but when I run this code snippet (included in `<head>`) I get null.

I read that starting with numbers (only option available) as an ID for an element [can cause problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306204/using-queryselector-with-ids-that-are-numbers), but I'm unable to set the ID as it is programmatically generated.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
  function setGclid() {
    var id = "971073_73591pi_971073_73591"

    console.log(document.getElementById(id)) //returns null

    //also tried this: console.log(document.querySelector("#\\39 71073_73591pi_971073_73591")) //returned null 


    if (!document.getElementById(id)) {
      console.log('checking')
      window.setTimeout(setGclid, 100); /* this checks the flag every 100 milliseconds*/
    } else {
      var gclid = getCookie('gclid');
      document.getElementById(id).value = gclid

      console.log('complete')
    }
  }
  setGclid();
```

Answer (score 0):

Id is dynamic (will keep on changing) for each pardot form fields.

Use classname instead, by default the input tag will come under p tag with that field's api name as it's class name, like below

```
<p class="form-field  first_name pd-text required required-custom    ">
    <label class="field-label" for="494811_96722pi_494811_96722">First Name *</label>
    <input type="text" name="494811_96722pi_494811_96722" id="494811_96722pi_494811_96722" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="40" onchange="" onfocus="">
</p>
```

to select this element use script like below

```
document.querySelector("p.first_name input")
```

Replace **first_name** with your field's API name